# Prevent user from editing the same record

Tags: java, mysql, percona

I'm developing a Multiple user application on same network usign MySQL & Java.
What I'm looking for is:
User A: Modifying Record 100
User B: Try to view or modify same record 100.

I want the application to return error message for User B, that record already editing by another user.

How can i do this?

Comment: Read about Threads in java.. Synchronise on your Record object

Comment: What you want is called a mutex: https://www.google.com/search?q=mutex

Answer (score 3):

Include an **edit_timestamp** in the tables of your database you want to prevent from multiple users updating, which you'll update every time anyone edit the row.

In your forms, include a hidden field **edit_timestamp** with the value stored in the row you're editing.

When you receive a edit form, check if the **edit_timestamp** of the row that you're editing hasn't changed. If it has changed, someone has edited the row and throw an error to the user. If it hasn't changed, update the row and the **edit_timestamp** field

Comment: i would add keep a edited_by field to store the user name of the last edited user, and an if important for business an audit table to store multiple edits . record id, user id, date, what was changed, old and new values etc